# Type error when trying using modules in Vuex/TS

Tags: typescript, vuex, typescript-typings

I am trying to strongly type Vuex without resorting to any additional typing packages and I am getting typing errors.

My RootState currently consists of a single slice, but the application will obviously grow.

```
// store/index.ts
export type RootState = {
    book: BookState;
}

export const store = createStore<RootState>({
    modules: {
        book,  // <- books gets error, quoted below
    },
});
```

The Books store follows:

```
// books/store/index.ts
export default {
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
    getters,
};

// books/store/state.ts
export const state: BookState = {
    books: [],
};

export type BookState = {
    books: Book[];
}

// books/store/getters.ts
export type Getters = {
    books(state: BookState): Book[];
}

export const getters: GetterTree<BookState, BookState> & Getters = {
    books: state => state.books,
};

// books/store/mutations
export type Mutations = {
    [MutationType.SetBooks](state: BookState, books: Book[]): void;
    [MutationType.SetLoading](state: BookState, value: boolean): void;
    [MutationType.SetCreateModal](state: BookState, value: boolean): void;
    [MutationType.SetEditModal](state: BookState, value: { showModal: boolean; bookId?: string | undefined }): void;
    [MutationType.SetListening](state: BookState, value: boolean): void;
    [MutationType.SetSnapshotLastUpdatedAt](state: BookState, value: string): void;
}

export const mutations: MutationTree<BookState> & Mutations = {
    [MutationType.SetBooks](state, books) {
        state.books = books;
    },
}

// books/store/actions
export const actions: ActionTree<BookState, BookState> & Actions = {
    // ...
}
```

The error is:

```
TS2322: Type '{ state: BookState; mutations: MutationTree<BookState> & Mutations; actions: ActionTree<BookState, BookState> & Actions; getters: GetterTree<...> & Getters; }' is not assignable to type 'Module<any, RootState>'.   Types of property 'getters' are incompatible.     Type 'GetterTree<BookState, BookState> & Getters' is not assignable to type 'GetterTree<any, RootState> | undefined'.       Type 'GetterTree<BookState, BookState> & Getters' is not assignable to type 'GetterTree<any, RootState>'.         Index signatures are incompatible.           Type 'Getter<BookState, BookState>' is not assignable to type 'Getter<any, RootState>'.             Type 'RootState' is missing the following properties from type 'BookState': books, loading, showCreateModal, showEditModal, and 4 more.
```

I understand that the book getters are most likely incorrectly typed, but cannot really figure out what exactly my mistake is. Is this the generics that I supplied to `GettersTree`?

Or is the structure imported into the book module incorrect?

### UPDATE

I found out that removing generic to `createStore` "clears" the error

`createStore({...})` is ok, while `createStore<RootState>({...})` is not ok.

Why?

Comment: hi! I have the same error, couldnt yet resolve it. In my case Im using a generic createStore and it still gives me an error. Would you mind telling me where do you get the `Mutations` type from? I cant seem to find in the vuex type declarations

Comment: @samthet Oh, ok, this is the type that contains your actual Mutations. I updated the question, it should help. Good luck!

Comment: Ive been searching a lot about static vuex typing and it seems that there is no out of the box solution, but this github repo seems to do the trick, you might want to try it out if you are tired of trying to make it work: https://github.com/ktsn/vuex-smart-module